# Integral inequality upper bound?

Tags: integration, inequality

I am dealing with a quantity that is defined by the following expression

$$g(a,n) = \frac{\int_0^\infty dx \frac{f(x)}{x}(1+a x^2)^n \int_0^\infty dx f(x) dx}{\int_0^\infty dx \frac{f(x)}{x}\int_0^\infty dx f(x) (1+a x^2)^n dx}$$

where

$n \in \mathbb{Z}, n\ge -1, a>0, a \in \mathbb{R}$

and

$f(x)$ is a function that is integrable over $[0,\infty]$ (can also be normalized to 1), is exponentially suppressed at large $x$, 
$f(x)< e^{-L x}$ for $L \ge L_0(x_0)$ and $x>x_0$
, and that near zero is $f(x) = \mathcal{O}(x^2)$.

Is there a way to find an upper bound for such quantity, for a fixed function $f$ and a fixed value of $a$?

In particular, i use

$f(x) = x(e^{-b(x-c)^2}-e^{-b(x+c)^2})$

PS: my guess would be

$g(a,n) \le g(a,0)=1$

at least for $a= 1, c<1, b=\frac{2}{3c^2}>1$